# Design a function to be reusable with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote `fadein` and `fadeout` effect on hover but i'm writing the code all over again i'm wondering if i could change some parameters so that i can use it only once for all.

The ids `#crep`, `#sal` and `#frueh` are links

**html**

```
<div class="carta3">
  <h1 id="crepes2"></h1>
  <table id="crepes">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="carta2">
  <h1 id="salate2"></h1>
  <table id="salate">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="carta1">
  <h1 id="fruehstueck2"></h1>
  <table id="fruehstueck">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

**jquery code**

```
// fadeout fadein
    $("#crep, .carta3").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".carta3 ,#crepes, #crepes2").stop().fadeIn();
            $("#salate, #salate2, #fruehstueck, #fruehstueck2").hide();   
         }, 
            function(){
            $(".carta3 ,#crepes, #crepes2").stop().fadeOut(50);
    });

// salate fadeout fadein
    $("#sal, .carta2").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".carta2 ,#salate, #salate2").stop().fadeIn();   
            $("#fruehstueck,#fruehstueck2, #crepes, #crepes2").hide();
         }, 
            function(){
            $(".carta2 ,#salate, #salate2").stop().fadeOut(50);
    });




    $("#frueh, .carta1").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".carta1 ,#fruehstueck, #fruehstueck2").stop().fadeIn();   
            $("#salate, #salate2, #crepes, #crepes2").hide();
         }, 
            function(){
            $(".carta1 ,#fruehstueck, #fruehstueck2").stop().fadeOut(50);
    });
```

Comment: Use classes instead of id, so you can target multiple elements with one function. Also, when using classes to trigger a function on multiple elements, it's a good idea to know how to use the keyword `this`, to be sure you're targeting the right context

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is reasonable but naive. When you find yourself duplicating jQuery like this you should write a little plugin. It's really very easy to do.